# Reconocer únicamente una tabla de Excel para mostrarla

Tags: c#, excel, tablas, oledb

Buen día, estoy creando una aplicación en **C#** en la cual debo subir un archivo de Excel para mostrarlo en un **DataGridView**. El problema es que los archivos de Excel no contienen únicamente una tabla sino que también una introducción antes de la tabla.

Esta es la hoja de Excel:

[image: Tabla de Excel]

Este es el resultado en el DataGridView:

[image: Resultado del DataGrid]

Modificando la hoja de Excel, dejando únicamente la tabla el DataGrid muestra el resultado que yo deseo. El problema es que no se debe editar el archivo ya que el formato mostrado se debe respetar

**Mi duda es si existe alguna manera de que la aplicación reconozca unicamente la tabla en una hoja de Excel** y así que el DataGrid se muestre de la siguiente manera:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Dejo el código que he utilizado hasta el momento:

```
private void btnAgregarEn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ruta = "";
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openfile1.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx";
            openfile1.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";
            if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                if (openfile1.FileName.Equals("") == false)
                {
                    ruta = openfile1.FileName;
                }
            }

            conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + ruta + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'");
            //MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + nombreHoja + "$]", conn);
            MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Enero$]", conn);
            dt = new DataTable();
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dgvEneroNuev.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mi entender, la distinción de lo que es una **introducción** y lo que tu denominas **tabla** es algo de tu negocio o dominio, no de **Excel**.

En tu código estás llenando un **DataTable** con la consulta (query) que le haces a una hoja de Excel en particular, que entiendo que se llama *Enero$*.

basado en esto:

```
MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Enero$]", conn);
dt = new DataTable();
MyDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Una posibilidad es que tu consulta(query) no traiga todo el contenido de esa hoja sino a partir de las filas que te interesan a ti y que para ti componen esa "Tabla".

Es decir algo como (**no es código real**):

```
MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Enero$] WHERE row >4", conn);
```

para poder así omitir esa **introducción** que tu mencionas.

Cuando haces estas consultas creo que tienes que tener en cuenta también las **columnas**.
Prueba con esto aunque no recuerdo del todo la sintaxis.

```
MyDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Enero$A5:J]", conn);
```

Lo que sería desde la Columna A fila 5 hasta la columna J.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, gracias.